# RPM virtual repo (with 2 remote repos) only first one in the list wokrs

Tags: artifactory, rpm, dnf

I created two remote virtual repos:
http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/9/AppStream/x86_64/os/
http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/9/BaseOS/x86_64/os/

then I created virtual repo with both remote. And it works, but looking for packets only in the first in the list  remote repo of that virtual repo. Is it something we need to fix/configure on JFROG side or dnf/yum side?

Create virtual repo with two remotes. Expecting to search packages from both remotes

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding you have created 2 remote repositories (RemoteA, RemoteB )and added them to one virtual repo VirtualA. In this case, when you try to resolve/fetch a package from a virtual repository, it first searches in RemoteA and if the package is not found in RemoteA then it will go to another repository "RemoteB"

In your case, all the requested packages are found in the first remote (RemoteA) which is the reason the requests are not going to other remote repo (RemoteB). You can set and enable "[Priority Resolution](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings)" in the Advanced configuration of the remote repo which will help to prioritize the resolution of artifacts from the preferred repositories.

The order by which repositories are queried is determined by the order in which they are listed in the configuration as described in [General Resolution Order](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-GeneralResolutionOrder) below.

You can get more information on the virtual repos working style [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-VirtualRepositories).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is the case. Let's say in repo A I have a package with the name "rsync" and in repo B, I have a package with the name "rsync-daemon"

So now, in virtual repo I set order AB

yum search rsync - ok, found rsync
yum search rsync-daemon - no packages found

Changing order to BA

yum search rsync - no packages found
yum search rsync-daemon - ok, found rsync-daemon